# How do I get my forward movement to match the direction of my camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to game development and I cant seem to make the forward movement of my player to match the direction my camera is facing. I'm in the process of learning how to make simple characters and simple character movement. I've gotten where I can press play and move forward, backwards, left, and right but if i "turn" around with the camera and press w it still moves positive on the Z-axis. Thanks in advance.

Here is my movement script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//My Movement Controller
public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;
    public float MovementSpeed =1;
    public float Gravity = 9.8f;
    private float velocity = 0;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        // player movement - forward, backward, left, right
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * MovementSpeed;
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MovementSpeed;
        characterController.Move((Vector3.right * horizontal + Vector3.forward * vertical) * 
    Time.deltaTime);
 
        // Gravity
        if(characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            velocity = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            velocity -= Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            characterController.Move(new Vector3(0, velocity, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my camera movement script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Smooth Mouse Look")]
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour 
{
     public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
     public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
     public float sensitivityX = 15F;
     public float sensitivityY = 15F;
     public float minimumX = -360F;
     public float maximumX = 360F;
     public float minimumY = -60F;
     public float maximumY = 60F;
     float rotationX = 0F;
     float rotationY = 0F;
     private List<float> rotArrayX = new List<float>();
     float rotAverageX = 0F;
     private List<float> rotArrayY = new List<float>();
     float rotAverageY = 0F;
     public float frameCounter = 20;
     Quaternion originalRotation;
     void Update ()
     {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
        {
            //Resets the average rotation
            rotAverageY = 0f;
            rotAverageX = 0f;
       
            //Gets rotational input from the mouse
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
       
            //Adds the rotation values to their relative array
            rotArrayY.Add(rotationY);
            rotArrayX.Add(rotationX);
       
            //If the arrays length is bigger or equal to the value of frameCounter remove the first value 
     in the array
            if (rotArrayY.Count >= frameCounter) {
                rotArrayY.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            if (rotArrayX.Count >= frameCounter) {
                rotArrayX.RemoveAt(0);
            }
       
            //Adding up all the rotational input values from each array
            for(int j = 0; j < rotArrayY.Count; j++) {
                rotAverageY += rotArrayY[j];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < rotArrayX.Count; i++) {
                rotAverageX += rotArrayX[i];
            }
       
            //Standard maths to find the average
            rotAverageY /= rotArrayY.Count;
            rotAverageX /= rotArrayX.Count;
       
            //Clamp the rotation average to be within a specific value range
            rotAverageY = ClampAngle (rotAverageY, minimumY, maximumY);
            rotAverageX = ClampAngle (rotAverageX, minimumX, maximumX);
       
            //Get the rotation you will be at next as a Quaternion
            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotAverageY, Vector3.left);
            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotAverageX, Vector3.up);
       
            //Rotate
            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {        
            rotAverageX = 0f;
            rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
            rotArrayX.Add(rotationX);
            if (rotArrayX.Count >= frameCounter) {
                rotArrayX.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < rotArrayX.Count; i++) {
                rotAverageX += rotArrayX[i];
            }
            rotAverageX /= rotArrayX.Count;
            rotAverageX = ClampAngle (rotAverageX, minimumX, maximumX);
            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotAverageX, Vector3.up);
            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion;        
        }
        else
        {        
            rotAverageY = 0f;
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
            rotArrayY.Add(rotationY);
            if (rotArrayY.Count >= frameCounter) {
                rotArrayY.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < rotArrayY.Count; j++) {
                rotAverageY += rotArrayY[j];
            }
            rotAverageY /= rotArrayY.Count;
            rotAverageY = ClampAngle (rotAverageY, minimumY, maximumY);
            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotAverageY, Vector3.left);
            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * yQuaternion;
        }
    }
    void Start ()
    {    
                Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (rb)
            rb.freezeRotation = true;
        originalRotation = transform.localRotation;
    }
    public static float ClampAngle (float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        angle = angle % 360;
        if ((angle >= -360F) && (angle <= 360F)) {
            if (angle < -360F) {
                angle += 360F;
            }
            if (angle > 360F) {
                angle -= 360F;
            }        
        }
        return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
    } 
}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line of your movement script:

```
characterController.Move((Vector3.right * horizontal + Vector3.forward * vertical) * 
Time.deltaTime);
```

You are moving to the right/left and forward/backward of a Vector3, which is always the same, what you want is this:

```
characterController.Move((transform.right * horizontal + transform.forward * vertical) * 
Time.deltaTime);
```

This way you can move to the right/left and forward/backward of your player current rotation.